# Generalization of group rings to quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The structure of a group ring $R[G]$, where $G$ is a group and $R$ is a ring is generalized to monoid rings $R[M]$, and also semigroup rings.

**Is there such a things as a "quotient group ring" $R[G/H]$?** Obviously it should be a quotient group $G/H$ with $H$ **not necessarily normal**, or it would be the same as a group ring. It should also be both a free module and a ring.

Comment: I mean I don't think there's a natural way of putting a multiplication on $G/H$ if $H$ isn't normal in $G$

Comment: What reason do you have to think that there would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think describing the induced representation $\text{Ind}_H^G 1$ may answer the question. Let $G$ be a finite group.

- Think to $\mathbb{C}[G]$ as a ring of linear maps, generated by $\{\pi(g),g \in G\}$, where $\pi(g)$ is the linear map $\mathbb{C}^{|G|} \to \mathbb{C}^{|G|}$ permuting the indices following the group law : $\forall f \in \mathbb{C}^{|G|}, \ \ \pi(g) f(g') = f(gg')$.
- $H$ is a subgroup. There are some $g_j \in G$ such that $G = \bigcup_{j=1}^{|G/H|} g_j H$ where the union is disjoint.

  For any $g \in G$ and $j$, there is some $i= i(g,j)$ such that $g g_j\in g_i H$, ie. for some $h\in H$, $g g_j = g_i h$ and $g g_i H = g_j H$.

  Let $\rho(g)$ be the corresponding linear map $\mathbb{C}^{|G/H|} \to \mathbb{C}^{|G/H|}$ permuting the indices this way : $\rho(g) f(g_j H) = f(g g_j H) = f(g_{i(g,j)} H)$.

  The $\mathbb{C}$ linear combinations of the $\rho(g)$ is a ring, call it $\mathbb{C}[G/H]$.

  In other words $\mathbb{C}[G/H]$ is a ring of linear maps acting on the vector space of right $H$-invariant functions $|G| \to \mathbb{C}$ (this formulation should work for non-finite groups)
- Thus $\rho(h), h  \in H$ isn't the identity, since it acts by left multiplication on those right $H$-invariant functions.

  Except of course when $H$ is normal, so that $g_j H = H g_j$ and right $H$-invariant implies left $H$-invariant, in which case $\mathbb{C}[G/H]$ is also the group ring of the group $G/H$.
- In term of $G$ modules ?  In general $\mathbb{C}[G/H]$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{C}[G]$.

Comment: In your second bullet point, the span of the image $\rho(G)$ in $\mathrm{End}_{\Bbb C}(\Bbb C[G/H])$ would be $\cong\Bbb C[G]/\langle A\rangle$ where $A$ is the augmentation ideal of $\Bbb C[N]\le\Bbb C[G]$ and $N$ is the normal core of $H$, right?

Comment: @anon Since $N= \bigcap_{g \in G} g^{-1} H g$ is normal in $G$, with $A = \{ \sum_{n \in N} a(n) \pi(n) \in \mathbb{C}[G], \sum_{n \in N} a(n) = 0\}$ then $\mathbb{C}[G/N] \cong \mathbb{C}[G]/\langle A\rangle$, where $\langle A\rangle= \{ \gamma \alpha, \gamma \in \mathbb{C}[G], \alpha \in A\}$, I'd say. Then $\mathbb{C}[G/H]$ should be a quotient of $\mathbb{C}[G/N]$ ?

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the kind of thing I was thinking of.

Comment: Do you know of any reference for this kind of construction?